# SSL Certificate of type .crt for Exchange Server 2017?

Tags: ssl, certificate, exchange-server

To secure our homepage we bought a Wildcard SSL domain certificate a while ago. Our hoster uses StarfieldTech as certificate provider, I can download the cert as "domain-name.crt" file.

My question is: Since we're also using Exchange Server 2017 under the same domain, can I use this cert as well? Does Exchange Server 2017 accept the .crt filetype? Or do I have to convert it to another format? How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you can use wildcard certificate to secure Exchange Subject alternative Names (SAN). So make sure that your SANs are covered in the certificate - mail.domain.com, autodiscover.domain.com etc. You can use .crt files. But get the password also

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Thanks Manu!
I will give this information to my coworkers and test this out.

Comment: Alright, my coworkers just confirmed that they can work with this approach. Thanks for the answer and the useful hints.

Comment: Glad to hear that the post helped you...Thanks